# Where will be the myserver.conf, hosts, and ports.conf in cPanel/WHM?

Tags: centos, cpanel, vhosts, whm

I want to customize my client's site with virtual host block. Manually I did this request on the Ubuntu server 18.04. But now I have the cPanel and the WHM access.

I read these official links.

[Modify Apache Virtual Hosts with Include Files](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA4/Modify+Apache+Virtual+Hosts+with+Include+Files)

[Modify Virtualhost Containers With Include Files](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Modify+Virtualhost+Containers+With+Include+Files)

But I messed regrading the `include files` and those directories as,

```
/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/ssl/2_2/$user/$domain/$includename.conf
```

and

```
/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/user/domain/includename.conf
```

And the following scripts

> To rebuild the httpd.conf file, run the following script:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf
> ```
>
> To restart Apache, run the following script:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/restartsrv_httpd
> ```

Please clearly tell how can I merge this to be put using cPanel and WHM.

**vhost**

```
<VirtualHost *:9876>
        ServerName 139.59.xxx.xxx
        DocumentRoot /home/username/newfile/doneapi/public

        <Directory /home/username/newfile/doneapi/public>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**hosts file**

```
127.0.0.1 139.59.xxx.xxx
```

**ports.conf**

```
Listen 9876
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since cPanel / WHM control panel is present, I'd recommend contacting their support team. Its free, you can open a ticket by visiting the URL support.cpanel.net. Since its their product, it would be better to get their advice on this.

Comment: @HarijithR, Thank you. Anyway shall I use include editor for this request?